# Image with transparent background in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I have image of object with transparent background for my Flutter app.
But Flutter shows this image with transparent background, as it is.
How do i hide transparent background of the image in Flutter?

Comment: show screenshots and codes

Comment: https://c7.uihere.com/files/556/141/68/yellow-submarine-clip-art-submarine-biomass-vector.jpg
here is image. I don't know what code to show. I just need that image to be without seen a transparent background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The image you are using is not a proper transparent PNG file. It's a JPEG. So, please use a proper transparent PNG file. Here are some difference between a JPEG and PNG:

- Both support true color or a palette of 16 million colors, PNG also
  supports 256 color and monochrome images.
- JPEG uses a lossy algorithm, PNG uses the ubiquitous lossless
  algorithm which we all know as ZIP.
- ***PNG supports alpha as well as single color transparency. JPEGS are
  opaque.***
- Compression ratio of images can be upto 50x for a JPEG but maybe at
  most 4:1 in PNGs for most images with many colors